# How to combine Dojo.Deferred + dojo.data.read

Tags: asynchronous, dojo

I have a chain of asynchronous events that i want to execute, some of them `fetch` commands.  I understand the basics of using `dojo.Deferred`, but all of my attempts so far to add a `fetch` callback have failed...

What im *trying* to do is 1) add a fetch call to my `Deferred` object 2) have that fetch function be run, possibly with some extra arguments and 3) pass on the 'fetched' values to the next callback in the chain... Here's what i've got:

```
var myDeferred = new dojo.Deferred();
myDeferred.addCallback(this.myStore.fetch({query:{//some query//}, 
    onComplete: function(items) { return items } })); //add the fetch callback? i think this is wrong...
myDeferred.addCallback(function(items) { console.log(items) }); //log the fetched items

myDeferred.callback(); //to fire
```

Comment: Since 1.5 you can use the .then() method on Deferreds to chain them easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to fire your deferred from the callback of the fetch

```
var myDeferred = new dojo.Deferred();
this.myStore.fetch({
    query:{//some query//}, 
    onComplete: function(items) { myDeferred.callback(items); }
})
myDeferred.addCallback(function(items) { console.log(items) }); //log the fetched items
```

If you have multiple fetches you should look into DeferredList and into returning a Deferred from the deferred-callback. Both can be used to create quite complex behavior.
You should also look into the new dojo 1.5 Deferred which have a simpler usage pattern, which might help you.